# How to load a java class in torquebox at startup?

Tags: jruby, torquebox

How do I go about loading a java class in torquebox at startup? Here is the issue I am running into, one of my gems needs a certain java class available (com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.VariableStack), it is available if I load irb in jruby in the local environment, but using the torquebox console it is not found. This causes the server to fail when it tries to boot as the gem needs this class. I believe I found a jar file (I THINK jaxp-ri-1.4.2.jar contains it) that contains this class but I have not been able to figure out how to load it successfully in torquebox at startup.

Answer (score 0):

TB's modules setup some class isolation by default - so you might not see internal classes such as `com.sun.xxx`. try looking into JBoss' proprietary descriptor `jboss-web.xml` to relax access to some of the packages.

here's how classes are isolated by default in TB/JBosss: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossClassLoadingUseCases